# Django How to update model object fields from external api data

Tags: python, django, database, api, django-models

I have a script which runs on a scheduler to get data from an api which I then intend to use this data to update the current database model information.

My model **ShowInfo** within main/models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ShowInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    latest_ep_num = models.FloatField()
    ld = models.BooleanField()
    sd = models.BooleanField()
    hd = models.BooleanField()
    fhd = models.BooleanField()
    following = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name = 'following', blank=True)
```

I managed to isolate the issue to this section of the script which runs but inserts duplicate shows with the same titles into the database:

```
    else: #test if api fails
        for t in real_title:
            if t in data_title:  #testing if the titles in the database and from the api match
                a = ShowInfo.objects.get(title=t)
                id = a.id
                b = next(item for item in show_list if item["title"] == t)
                a1 = ShowInfo(id = id, title = b["title"], latest_ep_num=b["latest_ep_num"], ld=b["ld"], sd=b["sd"],hd=b["hd"],fhd=b["fhd"])
                a1.save()
```

Some additional info about the lists (where **show_list** is a list of dictionaries gotten from an api):

```
database = ShowInfo.objects.values()
real_title = []
data_title = []

for show in show_list:
    real_title.append(show["title"])
for data in database:
    data_title.append(data["title"])
```

When the script runs I notice from browsing my database with DB Browser for SQLite that the objects were being **inserted** and not **updating** as i intended.

The script is supposed to catch shows with the same title from the api and the database and to update any changed information. Does anyone have any idea what is wrong with my **save()** method?

Comment: So you're trying to update the object retrieved by ```a = ShowInfo.objects.get(title=t)``` right?

Comment: `a = ShowInfo.objects.get(title=t) ` is trying to retrieve the object i wan to update. `a1.save` is supposed to update it

Comment: You mean `id` is duplicated?

Comment: From looking at my DB with DB Browser the IDs are not being duplicated but the entries are. Meaning that shows with the same titles are being inserted and not updating as I want it to

Comment: Try printing `id`.

Answer (score 0):

After a day of trial and error and scrounging around the internet I finally found a solution that worked for me.

For anyone interested, [this is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299659/12523715) that I found from another user on Stack which utilized overriding the internal save method to force an update and not insert if the current object with the same field is already in the DB.

Other methods such as doing `force_update=True` or `update_or_create()` did not work in my case.

Comment: I think the you don't really have to do overriding of anything here. ```a1 = ShowInfo(id = id, title = b["title"], latest_ep_num=b["latest_ep_num"], ld=b["ld"], sd=b["sd"],hd=b["hd"],fhd=b["fhd"])
                a1.save()``` This is where the problem is, you are creating a new object not updating an existing one. Though you said you already found a solution so it is what it is.

Comment: Could you clarify my misunderstanding? I had thought that calling a save method while specifying the specific id or pk would cause django to execute an update on that object with id already existing